# Simple onmouseover not working on eBay auction page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, getelementbyid, onmouseover

I have created a background which changes onmouseover of "test image". This works on a normal hosted account at http://zabb.co.uk/full_page_ebay_table_working.html but not when placed within an eBay auction http://cgi.ebay.co.uk/ws/eBayISAPI.dll?ViewItem&item=160653524585#ht_802wt_1398 (scroll down required).

Is there a way to fix this so that it works in eBay please? Thanks very much! Regards,

Paul

Comment: When you have a hammer.. everything looks like a nail! I mean, I really don't know your project needs, but from what I see here, I think you need to use CSS for this, instead of javascript.

Comment: Thanks iamserious, the brief is to have 16 thumbnail swatches on top of the main image which changes upon hover of the swatches. Absolute positioning however does not work with eBay (possible Iframe issue) so have to use tables hence I am now back to redesigning just for eBay at the moment.

Comment: aah, I get it now. wow ok. It's a lot trickier than I thought.. and it definitely out of css range.

Comment: really thanks for everyones help.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure to what extent eBay allows javascript, but I would have thought that you could achieve something with a CSS hover pseudo.

You could do the following, which would cause a background-image change on hover.

```
<style type="text/css">
table#bigPic { background: url(http://images.worldgallery.co.uk/i/prints/rw/lg/6/0/Derek-Hare-Sunset-Over-the-Sea-60196.jpg);
table#bigPic:hover { background: url(http://josefsipek.net/docs/s390-linux/hercules-s390/ssh-dasd1.png); }
</style>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks Sparky672 but the background image needs to change upon hover of the test image unfortunately as there will eventually be 16 smaller swatch images for hoverage!

Comment: Aren't there any 'plug-ins' available for Ebay that would give you something close to what you're trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

For security reasons, it is utterly impossible to use Javascript in an eBay page.

Comment: I like to see it as rather a challenge hehe

Comment: You're trying to create an XSS attack.  Good luck with that; since eBay is a very attractive target, many people have tried before you.  If you manage to succeed, you may get in trouble.

Comment: eBay do allow JavaScript, just not all JavaScript - http://pages.ebay.com/help/policies/listing-javascript.html

Comment: @AndyE: I don't see any Javascript allowed there.

Comment: @SLaks: see *"There are a few cases when you can use simple HTML (Hyper Text Markup Language) **and JavaScript functions** in listings..."* (emphasis mine).

Comment: @AndyE: Yes; I saw that.  However, in the actual details, Javascript is not mentioned.

Comment: I have tried on many attempts. Can sneakily include javascript but theres seems to be little coverage of this topic hence a lot of problems with this. eBay should really have more indepth documentation on this sort of topic. It's hit and miss for me. Thanks again!

Comment: SLaks: [just for you](http://www.ebay.com/dsc/i.html?_nkw=free-ClicPic&LH_TitleDesc=1&_armrs=1&_from=&_ipg=&_trksid=p2897) ;-) Browse to any item in the results and scroll down to the image gallery in the description.  It even looks like the sort of thing @Kelly is trying to do.

Comment: Exactly however the eBay version does not allow thumbnails to be different (just a scaled down version of original!) and a scroll which is not required. May however end up just using this but client may not be too happy! Will see..